# OpenGL error when running HFSS

Tags: nvidia, opengl

I have NVidia drivers as

Graphics:

```
   Card-1: Intel Device 591b bus-ID: 00:02.0
   Card-2: NVIDIA GP107M [GeForce GTX 1050 Ti Mobile] bus-ID: 01:00.0
   Display Server: X.Org 1.18.4 driver: nvidia
   Resolution: 1920x1080@60.00hz
   GLX Renderer: GeForce GTX 1050 Ti/PCIe/SSE2
   GLX Version: 4.6.0 NVIDIA 418.56 Direct Rendering: Yes
```

I am connecting the HFSS on server with vglrun xpra ...
I have encountered the following error:

> [VGL] ERROR: OpenGL error 0x0502
>   [VGL] ERROR: in readPixels--
>   [VGL]    475: Could not Read Pixels

Why is this problem sourced?
And how can I solve it?

Comment: You should specify the exact commands that you are using.